# How to transfer data from one device to another over wifi

Tags: android, node.js, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a todo list type of application, and want to run within intranet (over wifi). Where any one can add task and see other task within enviorment. So how can i transfer or sync data between the devices.

This application will be in android native or hybrid (Ionic).

Answer (score 2):

Try Following links, may be this can help you

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html
http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html

Answer (score 1):

Broadcast data all over the network and create a sender that Broadcast message or whatever you want to send in the network and create a listener in your app that always listen to some port for incoming updates ...

You have to create some mechanism or sort of an algorithm that will keep all the nearby devices updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running within the same intranet, I'd say the most reliable way to do this would be to create a RESTful API that's local to the network and have all of the devices refer to it for their data.

If you know a little PHP it's super easy to do, if not, it's super easy to learn!

1. Create a database with tables with structures suitable for what you want to store. I normally use MySQL for small projects
2. Use a convenient library like [NotORM](http://www.notorm.com/) to access the database records easily.
3. Decide on which actions you want to be able to carry, e.g. "Create Task", "Sync Tasks", "Mark Task Complete", then put together some API methods to handle that type of tasks using a convenient library like [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/).
4. Create an interface to your API in the Android project using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), and call whichever methods you need to interact with the server.
5. Make yourself a triumphant warm beverage of your choice to celebrate victory.

This method has the added advantage of security and reliability, in that it uses standard ports (you can even secure the server with HTTPS if need be), the ports wont be blocked by firewalls as it's all using port 80, you can use it off-site if you make the API accessible to external IPs, and all devices stay in sync with the master list whenever they pull down the list of tasks from the server.

You can also make a web interface that pulls from the same API so you can monitor tasks from a desktop machine.